# Creating a ‘typed’ effect with keyframes inside a table cell

Tags: html, css, keyframe

Using keyframes animation I’m trying to create a ‘typewriter’ affect, whereby a word slowly appears left to right as if typed.  For some reason, this works well within a `<div>` or `<p>`, but not in a table cell.  Outside the cell, the animation works correctly, ‘typing’ slowly left to right.  Inside a table cell, however, the whole word appears all at once.  In my search for a solution, I added a font color change to the keyframe.  Here, oddly enough, the font changes color slowly in both cases, as it should.  Can someone tell me why the same code works outside a cell but not inside?  I’m stumped. Thanks for any help.

Here’s the code:

```css
.typing {
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 6px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.typewriter-ani {
  animation: typewriter;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(8);
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes typewriter {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
    color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    width: 60px;
    opacity: 1;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="typing typewriter-ani">Welcome!</p>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="typing typewriter-ani">Welcome!</td>
    <td class="typing typewriter-ani">Welcome!</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="typing typewriter-ani">Welcome!</td>
    <td class="typing typewriter-ani">Welcome!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How about https://jsfiddle.net/bth94tqs/ like that?

Answer (score 0):

Modern browsers by default will assign the td element a display attribute of table cell.

```
display: table-cell;
```

Your code doesn't work because display is defaulting to table-cell. This value is supposed to take the entirety of the space so that it might cover all the relative coordinates of the grid. To understand the how browsers render tables you can check out: https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/single-page.html#concept-cell

One easy solution is to assign the table cells a new display value.

```
td {
       display: inline-block;
   }
```

I added display: inline-block to over ride the default user agent stylesheet.

JS-Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jamesvan/v6wq5qhb/

Comment: James,
I tried adding  display: inline-block; to the table definition, but it didn’t work.  Perhaps because what I posted was a simplication of what I’m trying to do.  Would you please look at my reply to damo-s above, which better explains my approach?  Perhaps that why your solution failed.
Thanks, 
Oliphant

Answer (score 0):

It appears it has something to do with the width rule in the animation. My guess is table cells just don't operate in the same way as block level elements when it comes to `overflow: hidden` and adjusting the width to smaller than its contents.

You can get around this by wrapping whatever element you want to appear "typed" in a block level element within the table cell and applying styles to that instead.

```css
.typing {
  text-align: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 6px;
  opacity: 0;
}
.typewriter-ani {
  margin: 0;
  
  animation: typewriter;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: steps(8);
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
@keyframes typewriter {
  0% {
    width: 0;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  1% {
    opacity: 1;
    color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    width: 60px;
    opacity: 1;
    color: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<p class="typing typewriter-ani">Welcome!</p>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><p class="typing typewriter-ani">Welcome!</p></td>
        <td class="typing typewriter-ani">Welcome!</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="typing typewriter-ani">Welcome!</td>
        <td class="typing typewriter-ani">Welcome!</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks damo-s,  Wrapping the text at the block level really does make the ‘typewriter’ work. 
However, I simplified things a bit.  I’m really calling 'typewriter-ani’ for each cell with a mouse click:
document.getElementById(‘myCell1’).className = 'typewriter-ani';

In turn, each cell is defined by an ID: #myCell1 { opacity: 0;}.  The table looks more like this:
   <td>
       <p id="myCell1">Welcome!</p>
   </td>
So while I can make the animation work by calling typewriter-ani directly from within the cell’s <div>, I can’t get it to work indirectly, i.e., by using getElementById.

Oliphant

Comment: Oh, well that's important information :)  Do you still have the `typing` class or are all those rules in your `typewriter-ani` class? `className` you probably know replaces all the contents of the `class` attribute while `classList.add` does not - it adds to the existing classes.